# Can't access to View Helper from another view called in a controller [Zend Framework]

Tags: php, zend-framework, include, view-helpers

I need to send an email via `Zend_Mail` within my `IndexController`. Instead of setting up the body of my email in a variable, I'd rather use another view.
Here's how I call my view in the controller:

```
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->addScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH.$this->getRequest()->getModuleName().DS.'views'.DS.'scripts'.DS.'email')
         ->setHelperPath(LIB_PATH.'Ms'.DS.'View'.DS.'Helper');
    $view->subscription = $subscription;
```

I then configure the email and send it like so:

```
    $mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
    $mail-> // ...
         ->setBodyHtml($view->render('checkout.phtml'))
         ->send();
```

In `scripts/email/checkout.phtml` I use two view helpers which work perfectly fine when called in the default view of the controller. But not anymore when used in `checkout.phtml`.

I used both `$this->price($myTotal)` and `$this->getHelper('Price')->price($myTotal)` and none of them work.

The error I get is : `Plugin by name 'Price' was not found in the registry; used paths:
Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/;C:\wamp2.4\www\abo\library\Ms\View\Helper/`. The weirdest thing being that it goes looking for helper in the right directory but can't find it.

Any thoughts/ideas?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to set helper path by adding a second argument like so:

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->setHelperPath(LIB_PATH.'Ms'.DS.'View'.DS.'Helper', 'Ms_View_Helper');
```